# what is the meaning of "so broken of my rest" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

what is the meaning of "so broken of my rest" in this context?

> On Friday night, March 31st, 1848, we concluded to go to bed early and
>   not permit ourselves to be disturbed by the noises, but try and get a
>   night's rest. My husband was here on all these occasions, heard the
>   noises, and helped search. It was very early when we went to bed on
>   this night – hardly dark. I had been **so broken of my rest** I was
>   almost sick. My husband had not gone to bed when we first heard the
>   noise on this evening. I had just lain down. It commenced as usual. I
>   knew it from all other noises I had ever heard before. The children,
>   who slept in the other bed in the room, heard the rapping, and tried
>   to make similar sounds by snapping their fingers.

Comment: Where does this passage come from? It reads as rather archaic to me, though not sure whether it is actually old, or just written to sound that way.

Answer (score 1):

This entire passage sounds archaic, however isn't too hard for me to understand.

"so broken of my rest" is referring to lack of sleep - 'broken sleep' would be a similar modern phrase. Basically, the narrator is saying that they have had so little sleep, for so long, that they are feeling ill.